# how to move a new mail (Excluding Re: & Fwd: ) to another folder in shared inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to move the received new mails in shared inbox excluding the (Re: and FWD:) to "In progress folder". When I execute it's not working.

Error popping up in this line `olReply.Move fldr`

[image]

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public WithEvents olItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    
    Set olItems = Session.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
    
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim olReply As MailItem
    Dim fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        
        If Len(Item.ConversationIndex) > 44 Then
            Exit Sub
        
        Else
        
            Set fldr = Outlook.Session.Folders("xxx@xxx.com").Folders("In Progress")
            olReply.Move fldr
        
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured out the code myself and it works perfectly. The below-mentioned code reads through the new mails which hits the shared mailbox and move to another folder if it is a new mail and skips Conversation mails.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Public WithEvents olItems As Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set olItems = Session.Folders("xxxxx@xxxx.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
    
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim olNameSpace As NameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olReply As MailItem
    Dim olObj As Object
    Dim olDestFolder As Folder
 
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        If Len(Item.ConversationIndex) > 44 Then ' Checks if the mail has conversation
            Exit Sub

        Else 

       Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xx.com").Folders("In Progress")'Set destination folder
            Item.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                
        End If
    
    End If
    
    End Sub
```